# SonarQube does not come back up after I enable PostGres and set sonar.properties

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

Setup SonarQube Version 6.4 (build 25310) and have it running after having issue not opening 9000 from previous question:
[Setting up SonarQube on AWS using EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44658510/setting-up-sonarqube-on-aws-using-ec2)

Now I am trying to setup PostGres via AWS RDS:

1. Setup PostgreSQL 9.6.2
2. Configure security for Sonar EC2 instance to allow inbound rules:
3. PostGreSQl/TCP/5432/0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
4. PostGreSQl/TCP/5432/Anywhere/0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
5. PostGreSQl/TCP/5432/Custom/Sonar Security group --> group for the sonar instance
6. VI sonar.properties file
7. `sonar.jdbc.username=XXXXXX`  --> Username used during RDS setup
8. `sonar.jdbc.password=XXXXXX`  --> Password used during RDS setup
9. `sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:sonardbpostgre.XXXXXXXXX.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432`
10. `cd ../bin/linux-x86-64/`
11. `./sonar.sh restart`

From what I can tell something in my config is not happy as it does try to start as I can see the `pid` come up but then it immediately gets killed.

Any suggestions?

If I uncomment the changes in the changes in `sonar.properties` it comes back up after restart.

Here is what I see after I try adding the config for the DB:

```
root@ip-172- linux-x86-64]# ls
lib  SonarQube.pid  sonar.sh  wrapper
[root@ip-172- linux-x86-64]# ./sonar.sh restart
Stopping SonarQube...
Stopped SonarQube.
Starting SonarQube...
Started SonarQube.
[root@ip-172- linux-x86-64]# ls
lib  sonar.sh  wrapper
[root@ip-172- linux-x86-64]# ls
lib  sonar.sh  wrapper
[root@ip-172- linux-x86-64]# ./sonar.sh restart
Stopping SonarQube...
SonarQube was not running.
Starting SonarQube...
Started SonarQube.
[root@ip-172- linux-x86-64]# ls
lib  SonarQube.pid  sonar.sh  wrapper
[root@ip-172- linux-x86-64]# ls
lib  sonar.sh  wrapper
```

Comment: ```2017-06-22 16:13:01 UTC::@:[2882]:WARNING:  unrecognized configuration parameter "rds.logical_replication"```  This was the only log I saw in the DB instance

Comment: And what do you see in your SonarQube server logs?

Comment: `WrapperSimpleApp: Encountered an error running main: org.sonar.process.MessageException: Bad format of JDBC URL: jdbc:sonardbpostgre.XXXXXXX.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432
org.sonar.process.MessageException: Bad format of JDBC URL: jdbc:sonardbpostgre.XXXXXX.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432 `

Is there a particular format?

Comment: Updated the jdca URL to include ` jdbc:postgresql://sonardbpostgre.~` and still won't come up but got this from the web.log and saw this:`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not connect to database. Please check connectivity and settings (see the properties prefixed by 'sonar.jdbc.').` so tracing that out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Format of JDBC URL for PostgreSQL is `jdbc:postgresql://<host>/<database>`. In your case the property should look like `sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://xxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/sonarqube`.

Comment: `017-06-22 20:54:15 UTC:172.31.22.8(38022):XXXXXX@sonarqube:[31172]:FATAL: database "sonarqube" does not exist`

Comment: @isaacweathers , you need to create first `sonarqube` database in your postgres DB server by using `create database sonarqube` command, you can do by using some command line client to postgres.

Comment: Ah. Makes sense. Let me try that out this morning and see if that helps. Thanks @AmitK

Comment: That was it @AmitK -- Made more sense once I logged in via `pgadmin4-1.5` -- definitely a useful tool for PostGre. Upvoted your answer. Thanks again. Is there a link to configuring the EC2 instance runinng sonarqube in AWS to use ELB/SSL and a Route53 domain or should I just look in the docs?

Comment: @isaacweathers , glad again i am able to help you here. i am not sure if there is a consolidate link with all the requirement although you can just follow the various other link for each steps.